# Canvas Image Draw don't work in all Browser

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this simple code for draw an image in a canvas but it's work only in Firefox

this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CANVAS</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="smallImage" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
<script>
var imgid = document.getElementById('smallImage');
var ctx = imgid.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
var immmagine = "flowers.jpg";
img.src = immmagine;
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably in your ff, due to testing, the image is cached. Draw only when the image is loaded, use an onload-event handler.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle. Check this and make changes. http://jsfiddle.net/EmSYq/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the onload event.

```
img.onload = function() {
   ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen the onload event on your image :

```
var imgid = document.getElementById('smallImage');
var ctx = imgid.getContext('2d'); 
var img = new Image();
var immmagine = "flowers.jpg";
img.src = immmagine;
img.onload = function ()
{
 ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```